# Excel VBA If Condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

For some reason the i'm running everytime into the condition even when it doesn't verifies.

```
If CC = "63165-POLIMENTO" And Format(registos.TextBox4, "#") < 0 Or Format(registos.TextBox4, "#") > ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("calculos2").Range("B4") Then
```

My problem is on greater and less operators , i believe they are misplaced.

Comment: Note `Format(registos.TextBox4, "#")` always returns a string not a number. This might cause strange issues when comparing against numbers. Better to convert it into a proper number type than into a string.

Comment: You also need to add Brackets in the form: If A And (B Or C) Then

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Format(___,"#")` ?

Comment: Also your `OR`'s are a little ambiguous.  ...like @Pierre44 mentioned... Excel can't guess whether you mean `A And (B Or C)` or `(A And B) Or C` etc

Comment: @ashleedawg Well, I think it will not guess but just go from left to right so it will always perform the first condition (here the `And`) and then take that result to perform the second (here the `Or`) so it will always do `(A And B) Or C` if no brackets are used. • Nevertheless it is a very good idea to use brackets for clarification here!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yeah, let's teach them right, instead of it "accidentally working" and expecting that next time...  Of course Excel's not going to *guess*, it was an expression. ‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
If CC = "63165-POLIMENTO" And _
    (Val(registos.TextBox4) < 0 Or _
      Val(registos.TextBox4) > Worksheets("calculos2").Range("B4")) Then
```

- `Val` converts the string to a number
- This says "`CC` has to match `63165-POLIMENTO`"  *AND* :

  - ***EITHER*** ( `TextBox4` is **negative**, ***OR***,
  - `TextBox4` is larger than `B4`  )

Comment: Do I see a Val? :-)

Comment: @QHarr yes i thought of you.. we don't know the data type

Comment: Still no results. When condition is supposed to be true it doesn't verifies.

Comment: @PedroGaspar You can debug your code. Go through it step by step (F8) and check the value of  `registos.TextBox4` and `Worksheets("calculos2").Range("B4")`. Note that `Range("B4")` might also return a text string not a value and try `Range("B4").Value` instead.

Comment: Given values should make the condition verifies but it just does not , i also tried usinge .Value but made no difference.

Comment: @PedroGaspar what exactly are these values that you get **during debug from the variables**?

Comment: Got it , the problema was from CC = registos.TextBox4 , as that would always fall into fake , it was my mistake. Anyways , thanks for the help and info.